# Format fonts in a Linux terminal

Tags: c

How can I format fonts in a Linux terminal using C?

[image]

Comment: In this case,I really want to print something and delete it ; and again print something where I printed earlier.Let's say I want to print "current time".Something like that.Is there a method I can use?

Comment: Try using a utility like [figlet](http://www.figlet.org/) or [toilet](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/toilet). With a suitable font, it should be possible to draw large characters from fixed-width blocks like ■. Alternatively, use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to draw spaces with different background colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts do not exist in the standard [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) or [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) programming language specification(s).

If you are writing a graphical application in C for Linux, consider using some library like [GTK](http://gtk.org/), [libSDL](https://www.libsdl.org/), etc...

If you want to do some [Ascii Art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) in a terminal (read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) webpage), be aware of [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and consider using some terminal output library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

Comment: I wanna use Ascii Art.thanks

Comment: If my answer fits, you could accept it.

Comment: thanks.ncurses would do the work

Answer (score 1):

Linux terminal can display only characters. Any art you want to draw on a terminal must be rendered using characters. The shape of the characters displayed is controlled by the user via terminal settings, not by you nor your code.

There are libraries that make pixel drawing using characters in termnal easier, like [Drawille](https://github.com/asciimoo/drawille).

Comment: I will look forward to use Drawille.thanks